# Как разделить доступ к одной таблице

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, acl

Язык PHP, Фреймворк Yii2, бд MySQL. Но по сути это не важно, вопрос по организации запроса данных.

Есть группа пользователей А. Они создают объекты и имеют к ним доступ. 
Есть такая же группа Б.

Группа А должна быть полностью изолирована от группы Б.

Как это решать на уровне приложения и в БД?

Я решал это так: создается таблица access, в которой конкретно прописывается, что к объекту таблицы **table** записи с ИД **1** доступ имеет пользователь номер **5**. Например.

Потом на уровне приложения при любом запросе данных я присоединяю кусок SQL, который смотрит, есть ли запись на данный объект \ объекты.

А для групп пользователей я проверял, есть ли доступ у админа \ реферера группы и у самого конкретного пользователя.

Это работает, но кажется, что можно сделать проще. 
Есть ли минусы, какие альтернативы?

Вроде бы вопрос должен быть популярен, но по запросам в гугл ничего такого не нашел. Гуглил что то типа "как разграничить доступ к объектам" в разных комбинациях. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Я верно понимаю, что группа Б занята тем же, что и группа А? и весь гемор - не дать одним шариться в объектах, созданных другими? Тогда в первом приближении - выносим всю логику на сервер, перекрываем доступ к таблицам данных, а отбор по установленным правам выполняют процедуры, которые сами работают от имени типа админа и имеют доступ ко всем данным, но отдают лишь то, что текущему юзеру можно. А у самих юзеров в принципе нет средств доступа - ни к данным напрямую, ни к программному коду серверной логики (процедуры, функции, представления). Насколько сие реализуемо в рамках фреймворка - хз.

Comment: К примеру, есть облачная ЦРМ. Одна компания хранит своих клиентов и другая. Конечно же, они не должны видеть клиентов друг-друга. Ваше предложение я не совсем понял. Доступа к коду и базе ни у кого нет. Процедуры на уровне базы данных? А что они будут решать? Подставлять дополнительные критерии типа " AND id IN(SELECT * FROM access ...)"?